# Mumps Syntactical conflicts

Tags: mumps

I am learning Mumps language while analyzing code got a doubt which is

what is difference between B%% vs %%B.

But refference doc the syntax i have seen only %%B format but in code they had use like
  B%%

Bhas

Comment: Can you show some line of the code you are analyzing. I think that a double % is not allowed in the current MUMPS implementations. Is %B a local variable or a routine name ?

Answer (score 4):

% prefix is a convention.  It doesn't mean anything to the M(UMPS) interpreter, but does to the programmer.  Often % variables are meant to be "scratch" or temporary variables which shouldn't be used for anything more than a line or two of code.  e.g.

```
for %ln=1:1:maxNum do ImportantThing(%ln)  ; loop over lines 1 through maxNum
```

In normal code you'd declare (new) a variable and use it properly, but this sort of thing is common when introducing "plugin" code, such as an "after booking patient appointment" programming hook for some EHR application.

Answer (score 3):

Preceding or ending a variable name with "%%" is allowed.  I am not aware of a special significance of using "%'s" in MUMPS variable names, but it is a common 'convention.'  Speculating here, but I do note that $,^,& all have special meaning when part of MUMPS variable names and "%" is located near all three in both ascii value and keyboard position.

Comment: I beg to differ with you. A local or global variable name in Standard MUMPS may start with a single percent "%" but not more than one. Routines and tags also may start with a single percent "%" character.

Comment: Well, you have had me googling for the last 10 minutes.  I cannot find a link to support my assertion, but can say that I worked with a PC based implementation in 1992 that served code that made liberal use of "%%" variables.  As I am writing this, I wonder if asking "what is the first character in something like ^%%" might not muddy the waters of this discussion.  The original post here seems to be asking about special meaning for %%.  I do see it used with mumps variables, but have never read an associated specific import.  Have you?

Answer (score 1):

**Programs, Globals**

In standard MUMPS systems, there is a MGR UCI, where the system and utility programs resides. If a program name begins with "%", it is accessible from other UCIs, too, utility programs' names are beginning with "%", e.g. "%STA" (job status), "%GE" (global edit) and so on. Only programs in MGR UCI could begin with "%".

Also, globals beginning with "%", which resides in MGR UCI, can be accessed from other UCIs.

So, using "%" as the first character of a program or global is the part of the system (or may say, the language).

**Locals**

MUMPS is a very old stuff, the original language has no local variable support (all the subroutines and main program shares a common namespace). Anyway, user programs can call other programs, utility programs as well: DO FUNCT^%UTILPRG. By convention, utility programs use variable names beginning with "%", so they will no conflict with user program's variables.

So, using "%" as the first character of a local variable, is only a convention, but it is used in utility programs.